# Double FOREIGN KEY, i.e. how to create a table with two different FOREIGN KEYs that reference a single PRIMARY KEY in another table - DDL

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I have an issue with my SQL syntax when creating a table with a set of Foreign Key (Orig_Dept_ID & New_Dept_ID) that references Dept_ID in the Department Table.

Below is my sql syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT_TRANSIT
    (Orig_Dept_ID int,
    New_Dept_ID int,
    CONSTRAINT department_fk foreign key (Orig_Dept_ID, New_Dept_ID)
             REFERENCES Department(Dept_ID)
    );
```

Could someone please advise on how I should go about doing this?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities here:

- **1)** is that it is a case of 2 fields in the same table being `FOREIGN KEY`s pointing to the same field in the parent table.
- **2)** is that this is an example of an [**Associative Entity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity). These are also called joining, linking or many-to-many tables.

## 1. Double **`FOREIGN KEY`**.

This is quite simple to resolve.

You have two tables - `department` and `dept_transit` (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fe83608820e3307c429cdb0423a03040)):

```
CREATE TABLE department
(
  department_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- other fields,
  -- other fields,
  CONSTRAINT department_pk PRIMARY KEY (department_id)
);

CREATE TABLE dept_transit
(
  dt_original_dept_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  dt_new_dept_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT dt_original_dept_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (dt_original_dept_id) REFERENCES department (department_id),
  CONSTRAINT dt_new_dept_id_fk      FOREIGN KEY (dt_new_dept_id)      REFERENCES department (department_id)
  -- optional here CONSTRAINT dept_transit_pk PRIMARY KEY (dt_original_dept_id, dt_new_dept_id)
);
```

A few things to notice:

- my solution uses `long_variable_names`! Many years of experience have taught me that you are **far** better off making your variable names (table_names, field_names and `PK`s, `FK`s &c.) as long and as meaningful as necessary. This makes life much easier for debugging and more than outweighs the trouble of the extra typing! Also, note the singular name for `department`! YMMV :-)
- I always try to keep fieldnames unique within a **schema** (e.g. `new_dept_id`, `dt_new_dept_id`) - this helps greatly with logic when joining tables. I make exceptions for `NATURAL KEY`s, but not surrogate ones as is the case here.
- My own personal preference is for SQL keywords to be in upper-case and for the variables (tables, fields &c.) to be in `lower_snake-case`. This allows the eye to readily pick out different elements when debugging &c. If you look up SQL coding standards on the web, you will find lots of debate about this (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522356/what-sql-coding-standard-do-you-follow)). The main thing is to pick a standard (for yourself, company, whatever) and **STICK TO IT**.
- Not entirely sure of requirements, but I think that (for MySQL) a `TRIGGER` will be required for any requirement that `original_dept_id` and `new_dept_id` be different (which makes sense - I think). 
  Unfortunately, MySQL still (**Amazingly**) doesn't allow for `CHECK CONSTRAINT`s. See the **MUCH** nicer solution possible with PostgreSQL [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=91ccd87b87d9e46e4a55de4d12f8ddec). A good reason to switch to the **far** superior PostgreSQL if you're not too invested in MySQL! :-)

## 2. **Joining Table**.

If this is the case, I would do something like the following (fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8cbd17b8d1c9999ac38d18a1f70bc6a9)):

```
CREATE TABLE original_dept
(
  original_dept_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- other fields,
  -- other fields,
  CONSTRAINT original_dept_pk PRIMARY KEY (original_dept_id)
);


CREATE TABLE new_dept
(
  new_dept_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- other fields,
  -- other fields,
  CONSTRAINT new_dept_pk PRIMARY KEY (new_dept_id)
);



CREATE TABLE dept_transit
(
  dt_original_dept_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  dt_new_dept_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT dt_original_dept_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (dt_original_dept_id) REFERENCES original_dept (original_dept_id),
  CONSTRAINT dt_new_dept_id_fk      FOREIGN KEY (dt_new_dept_id)      REFERENCES new_dept (new_dept_id),
  CONSTRAINT dept_transit_pk PRIMARY KEY (dt_original_dept_id, dt_new_dept_id)
);
```

- The `PRIMARY KEY` of the joining table is a natural one, make up of the `PK`s of both of the entities that comprise it.

Comment: Hi Verace, thank you for your advice. Both original_dept_id and new_dept_id are referencing to 1 single field on the Parent table - Department, which is Dept_Id.

Comment: OK - so it's the `Double FOREIGN KEY` solution? I'll leave in the other bit in (put a bit of work into it). If you found it helpful, you might upvote it - which might help others to find the answer to their problem (as well as giving me points! :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Make a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint for each separately.